# Expand bootstrap accordion panel-body if embedded flask wtf form fails to validate

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, flask-wtforms

I have a flask-wtf form whose fields are spread across two accordion panel-bod[ies] as shown in the code snippet below.

I'd like to have the two panel-bod[ies] to expand if the form fails to validate on submit such that any validation errors will be evident (otherwise errors will be hidden under the collapsed bodies.

How can I achieve this?

Current code snippet below.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          1. Heading One
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <form class="form form-group" method="post" role="form">
              <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.field1) }}</div>
              <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.field2) }}</div>
              <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.field3) }}</div>
              <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.field4) }}</div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          2. Heading Two
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <form class="form form-group" method="post" role="form">
              <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.field5) }}</div>
              <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.field6) }}</div>
              <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.field7) }}</div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form class="form form-group" method="post" role="form">
  <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I established that its probably not good practice to have any fields that may fail to validate inside collapsable accordion panel bodies. I have therefore ensured that all fields inside the collapsable panel bodies can't fail validation (using SelectFields, IntegerRangeFields,...). This was sufficient for my use-case (though I can think of other use-cases where this workaround wouldn't have been applicable).